# <svg> not fit into its embeded <path>

Tags: svg, bootstrap-4

I am using BootStraps CSS framework version 4.6, in below HTML

```
<div class="d-inline-block col-6">
          {% if not item.comment.is_removed and allow_feedback %}

            {% if show_feedback and item.likedit_users %}
               <a class="text-base font-bold" title="{{ item.likedit_users|join:'<br/>' }}">
                  {{ item.likedit_users|length }}
               </a>
            {% endif %}

            <a class="d-inline-block" onclick="document.getElementById('like_comment_{{ item.comment.id }}').submit();">Test<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="d-inline" {% if user.username in item.likedit_users %} fill="currentColor" {% else %} fill="none" {% endif %} fill-opacity="0.5" stroke="currentColor"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M14 10h4.764a2 2 0 011.789 2.894l-3.5 7A2 2 0 0115.263 21h-4.017c-.163 0-.326-.02-.485-.06L7 20m7-10V5a2 2 0 00-2-2h-.095c-.5 0-.905.405-.905.905 0 .714-.211 1.412-.608 2.006L7 11v9m7-10h-2M7 20H5a2 2 0 01-2-2v-6a2 2 0 012-2h2.5" /></svg>
            </a>

            <form class="d-inline-block" id="like_comment_{{ item.comment.id }}" method="post" action="{% url 'comments-xtd-like' item.comment.id %}">{% csrf_token %}</form>

          {% endif %}
        </div>
```

**However, I found the size of `<svg>` was too large comparing with its embedded `<path>`.**

Size of parent `<div>`.

[image]

Size of first `<a>` within parent `<div>`

[image]

Size of second `<a>` within parent `<div>`

[image]

Size of `<svg>` within second `<a>`

[image]

Size of `<path>` within `<svg>`

[image]

**Q: How can I make `<svg>` shrink to fit into its embedded `<path>` please?**
I have tried `height`, `width`, `viewBox` attributes, all did not work out for me.

Comment: You use height width and viewBox attributes. Perhaps if you show us what values you're trying to use for them we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: As Robert said the key is the viewBox attribute. Let's say you change viewBox from `0 0 400 200` to `0 0 80 40`, some of the empty space will go away. If you can give an `id` to the `path` and then use [.getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) you can find out the exact location and dimensions of the path. Using those you can change the viewBox attribute.

Comment: thanks for your replies. I tried `<svg class="h-25 w-25">` (from 25% to 100%) along with `viewBox = "0 0 4 4"` (from 4, to 8, 16, 24, 96, 120, 240), unfortunately, `<svg>` is still occupying much larger size than its embedding `<path>`.